# Grabbing Minutes + Hours for Opening / Closing Times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, time, timing

I have some code set up to display a different message based on the opening / closing time. It works great, but the issue is the opening hours are 7:30am not just 7am. I have tried adding getMinutes (thehours < 7 + getMinutes <= 30) but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
let date = new Date();
let dayOfWeekNumber = date.getDay();
let nameOfDay;
let quote;
let thehours = date.getHours();
let theminutes = date.getMinutes();

switch(dayOfWeekNumber){
    case 0: 
        nameOfDay = 'Sunday';
        if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 7) {
            quote = 'Closed Today - Opens Monday at 7:30am';
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        nameOfDay = 'Monday';
        if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 7) {
                quote = 'Closed Now - Opens at 7:30am';

            } else if (thehours >= 7 && thehours < 18) {
                quote = 'Open Now - Closes at 6pm';

            } else if (thehours >= 18 && thehours < 23) {
                quote = 'Closed Now - Opens tomorrow at 7:30am';
            }
        break;
    case 2:
        nameOfDay = 'Tuesday';
        if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 8) {
                quote = 'Closed Now - Opens at 7:30am';

            } else if (thehours >= 8 && thehours < 18) {
                quote = 'Open Now - Closes at 6pm';

            } else if (thehours >= 18 && thehours < 23) {
                quote = 'Closed Now - Opens tomorrow at 7:30am';
            }
        break;
    case 3:
        nameOfDay = 'Wednesday';
        if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 8) {
                quote = 'Closed Now - Opens at 7:30am';

            } else if (thehours >= 8 && thehours < 18) {
                quote = 'Open Now - Closes at 6pm';

            } else if (thehours >= 18 && thehours < 23) {
                quote = 'Closed Now - Opens tomorrow at 7:30am';
            }
        break;
    case 4:
        nameOfDay = 'Thursday';
        if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 8) {
                quote = 'Closed Now - Opens at 7:30am';

            } else if (thehours >= 8 && thehours < 18) {
                quote = 'Open Now - Closes at 6pm';

            } else if (thehours >= 18 && thehours < 23) {
                quote = 'Closed Now - Opens tomorrow at 7:30am';
            }
        break;
    case 5:
        nameOfDay = 'Friday';
            if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 8) {
                quote = 'Closed Now - Opens at 7:30am';

            } else if (thehours >= 8 && thehours < 18) {
                quote = 'Open Now - Closes at 6pm';

            } else if (thehours >= 18 && thehours < 23) {
                quote = 'Closed Now - Opens tomorrow at 7:30am';
            }
        break;
    case 6:
        nameOfDay = 'Saturday';
        if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 7) {
            quote = 'Closed Now - Opens at 7:30am';
        } else if (thehours >= 7 && thehours < 12) {
                quote = 'Open Now - Closes at Noon';
        } else if (thehours >= 12 && thehours < 23) {
                quote = 'Closed Now - Opens at 7:30am Monday';
        }
        break;

}

    jQuery('.openingCincinnati').append(quote);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<h2>Cincinnati, Ohio</h2>
<div class="openingCincinnati"></div>
</div>
```

So - the question. How do I display the text using half hours?

Comment: What do you mean by "half hours"?

Comment: The opening time is 7:30am - I need to be able to display the text using half hours or 30 minutes of time.

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: So for Monday, it would need to say something like: if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 7 + theMinutes <= 29)  with the output being if the hours are greater than 12:01am and less than 7:29am, "Office Closed - Opening at 7:30am"

Comment: Right now, it is displaying this text at 7am instead of 7:30am.

Comment: The code in your question is executable, I ran it and it says "Closed Now - Opens tomorrow at 7:30am", isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, but it shows that text between 12:01am and 7am. I need it to display between 12:01am and 7:29am.

Comment: Alright, understood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be vastly simplified and you can just set up the time of opening and closing

We would need a timezone too if you want to service other timezones but that is more code.

```js
const getQuote = () => {
  let now       = new Date();
  let year      = now.getFullYear();
  let month     = now.getMonth();
  let date      = now.getDate();
  let dayNumber = now.getDay();
  let opening   = new Date(year, month, date, 7, 30, 0, 0).getTime();
  let closing   = new Date(year, month, date, 18, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
  let saturday  = dayNumber === 6;
  let sunday    = dayNumber === 0;
  let open      = !sunday && now.getTime() >= opening && now.getTime() < closing;
  if (open) return 'Open Now - Closes at 6pm';
  return `Closed ${sunday ? "Today" : "Now"} - Opens ${saturday || sunday ? "Monday" : "Tomorrow"} at 7:30am`;
}

$('.openingCincinnati').append(getQuote());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2>Cincinnati, Ohio</h2>
  <div class="openingCincinnati"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! I figured there was a way to simplify, this makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: I tweaked it some more, just because I should